# Smooth maps between manifolds are continuous

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

The comments in this question [Smooth maps (between manifolds) are continuous (comment in Barrett O'Neill's textbook)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56544/smooth-maps-between-manifolds-are-continuous-comment-in-barrett-oneills-tex) seem to suggest that a smooth map "in charts", id est satisfying the definition

A mapping $\phi:M\rightarrow N$ is *smooth* provided that for every coordinate system $\xi$ in M and $\eta$ in N the *coordinate expression* $\eta\circ\phi\circ\xi^{-1}$ is Euclidean smooth.

might not be continuous.

Here, I'm thinking *every* meaning every coordinate system in the maximal atlas.
I am not sure if O'Neil uses maximal atlases but I would like to know the answer for maximal atlases all the same. The definition of maximal atlas can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_structure.

Since in this definition, I am not guaranteed that the domain of $\eta\circ\phi\circ\xi^{-1}$ is open let's say that here *smooth* means that it is the restriction of a smooth map defined on an open set. Does there exist a counterexample of a map satisfying this property that is not continuous?

Answer (score 3):

The remark in the accepted answer in that post refer to the following equivalent definitions of smoothness of a map $f : M \to N$ between manifolds (that automatically implies continuity)

- $\color{blue}{(\text{Avoid dealing with domain})}$ $f$ is smooth if for every $p \in M$, there exists smooth charts $(U, \varphi)$ containing $p$ and $(V,\psi)$ containing $f(p)$ such that $f(U) \subseteq V$ and the composite map $\psi \circ f \circ \varphi^{-1}$ is smooth from $\varphi(U)$ to $\psi(V)$.
- $\color{blue}{(\text{Directly impose openness of domain})}$ $f$ smooth if for every $p \in M$, there exists smooth charts $(U, \varphi)$ containing $p$ and $(V,\psi)$ containing $f(p)$ such that $U \cap f^{-1}(V)$ **is open** in $M$ and the composite map $\psi \circ f \circ \varphi^{-1}$ is smooth from $\varphi(U \cap f^{-1}(V))$ to $\psi(V)$.
- $\color{blue}{(\text{Impose openness by continuity})}$ $f$ is smooth if **$f$ is continous** and there exists smooth atlases $\{(U_{\alpha},\varphi_{\alpha})\}$ and $\{(V_{\beta},\psi_{\beta})\}$ for $M$ and $N$ respectively, such that for each $\alpha$ and $\beta$, $\psi_{\beta} \circ f \circ \varphi_{\alpha}^{-1}$ is a smooth map from $\varphi_{\alpha}(U_{\alpha} \cap f^{-1}(V_{\beta}))$ to $\psi_{\beta}(V_{\beta})$.

An exercise in Lee's $\textit{Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, 2nd ed}$ illustrate what can go wrong if we drop the requirement that the domain should be open in the second definition : The following function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ (with $\mathbb{R}$ with standard maximal atlas) defined as
$$
  f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
                                   1 & \text{if $x \geq 0$} \\
                                   0 & \text{if $x<0$}.
  \end{cases}
$$
is clearly not continous but it is smooth in the sense of second definition minus openness of domain : as you can see, the composite map $\text{Id}_{(1/2,3/2)} \circ f \circ \text{Id}_{(-1,1)}^{-1}$ is a smooth map from $\text{Id}_{(-1,1)} \big( (-1,1) \cap f^{-1}(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2})  \big) = [0,1)$ to $(1/2,3/2)$.

Here is how one can modifiy example above to find a counterexample for the third definition (minus continuity of course) : Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the same function as above, with domain $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with atlas contain only identity chart $(U,\varphi)=(\mathbb{R},\text{Id}_{\mathbb{R}})$, but atlas of the codomain $\mathbb{R}$ consist of two charts $(V_1,\psi_1)=(\frac{1}{4},\infty), \text{Id}_{(\frac{1}{4},\infty)}$ and $(V_2,\psi_2) = (-\infty,\frac{3}{4}), \text{Id}_{(-\infty,\frac{3}{4})}$. So that now $f$ is not continous but for each $\beta$, $\psi_{\beta} \circ f \circ \varphi^{-1}$ is a smooth map from $\varphi(U \cap f^{-1}(V_{\beta}))$ (which is either $[0,\infty)$ or $(\infty,0)$) to $\psi_{\beta}(V_{\beta})$. In short, we just throw away charts where the representation of $f$ in these charts not smooth/continous but still have enough charts to cover the manifolds.

Comment: What about the definition of my question that requires that the map is smooth when read through all charts? This example looks not to be a counterexample in this case as I can take the whole real line as a chart.

Comment: @NicolòCavalleri $f$ is smooth at $x=0$ because the representation map is the restriction of the constant map $F\equiv 1$ on $\mathbb{R}$. There's no need to insist the chart must be all of $\mathbb{R}$ since the definition require us to find only one.

Comment: What definition? Your definition does require only one chart but mine asks that the representation map is smooth for every choice of charts in the maximal atlases of the two manifolds. Under normal circumstances (ie the map is continuous) the two are equivalent, but are they now?

Comment: @NicolòCavalleri Ok. Now i have a feeling that the counterexample that you want is for the third definition above which is the same as Barrett O'neils definition. I have one example in mind. Let me add this to my answer.

Comment: @NicolòCavalleri I think it's ok now.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer and your comments! They are really nice and didactic examples! However, the reason why I asked my question is that I am formalizing stuff in Lean (a proof assistant) and I'm thinking about using the above definition with maximal atlases, so I'd really need to know if the above definition with maximal atlases implies or not that a map is continuous. I actually think it does but I can't really prove it formally. If it does not, I think that in order to find a counterexample one needs to use a manifold that cannot be covered with only one chart.

Comment: I will edit my question to make it clearer, probably it is not very clear.